# Magento 2 can't update customer custom attribute value at customer observer(customer_save_after)

Tags: magento-2.1, event-observer, customer

I am trying to save customer custom attribute value at customer_save_after observer. but observer script is not working at observer but that script working at contoller.

events.xml

```
<event name="customer_save_after">
<observer name="VestricsM2_Connector_Customer_Save_After" instance="VestricsM2\Connector\Observer\CustomerSaveAfter" /> </event>
```

Observer/CustomerSaveAfter.php

```
protected $customerRepository;

protected $_logger;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
) {
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->_logger = $logger;
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
}

/**
 * customer register event handler
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 * @return void
 */
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

    if($customer->getId()){
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load('1');
         $customerRepository->setUpdatedinsap('1');
         $customerRepository->save();

       /* $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP .'/var/log/observer-log-file.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info($customerRepository->getData());*/

    }
```

Comment: whats your custom attribute value name?

Comment: Rakesh , my custom attribute name is "updatedinsap", but that above script working in controller

Comment: have you check customer id is getting or not?

Comment: i checked with this script $customerRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load('1');  i am getting data in log file

Answer (score 1):

Using **CustomerRepositoryInterface** you can save your custom customer attribute value,

Save your customer attribute value using `try/cache` block,

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

    if($customer->getId()){
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getId());
        $customer->setCustomAttribute('updatedinsap',1);
        try {                
            $customer = $this->customerRepository->save($customer);
        }catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
   return;

}
```

Comment: Rakesh, am facing same issue.

Comment: please first remove var/generation folder from root.

Comment: actually i removed total var folder and done upgrade & compile

Comment: which error are thrown please share.

Comment: the page is continuously loading then i have restart Apache sever other wise it's not working. in debug log " cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":[],"mode":"all"},"is_exception":false} [] "

Comment: try to add return after if condition and check.